# Lua - find/remove duplicate rows in a .csv file to create a pure/unique list

Tags: csv, lua

I have a 3000+ row .csv file that I created by pulling multiple .csv sources together - example of the content is below.

```
NEC;    35;     -1;     10
RC5;    0;      -1;     12
Panasonic;      176;    0;      61
RC5;    21;     -1;     1
RC5;    21;     -1;     1
NEC;    0;      -1;     0
RECS80; 4;      -1;     30
NEC;    1;      249;    3
Denon;  1;      -1;     40
NEC;    132;    60;     33
```

Please could someone let me know how I can create a new .csv file from the above that only has unique rows ?

If possible please could someone go on to explain how I could do this for both my existing .csv file and also at the an Lua array/table creation phase - many thanks !..

FYI - my new Lua code uses a loop and the following to populate the .csv

```
local info = table.concat ({protocol, D, S, F}, '; ')
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to probably read the lines one by one and keep track of those lines you've already seen without parsing them:

```
local csv = assert(io.open("test.csv", "r"))
local lines = {}
for line in csv:lines() do
  if not lines[line] then
    print(line)
    lines[line] = true
  end
end
```

This should print all unique lines from text.csv to the standard output (in the same order as they appeared in the file).

You can also use [uniq](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniq) in combination with `sort` if they are available on your system.

If you need to apply the same logic to lines in a table, then something like this should work (assuming the lines are in table `tt`):

```
local lines = {}
for _, line in ipairs(tt) do
  if not lines[line] then
    print(line)
    lines[line] = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Many thanks, what would I need to do differently to find duplicate rows when it’s in a Lua table/array ?

Comment: Same thing, but instead of iterating over `csv:lines` you'll need to use `ipairs` to iterate over the table.

Comment: Thanks Paul, sorry but I’m not sure exactly how the rest would work to see only the unique ones and the count ? If it helps the table/array is called ‘tt’  ? Is it something like this - for lines  in ipairs(tt) do
  if not tt[line] then
    print(line)
    tt[line] = true
  end
end

Comment: something similar to this, yes. Keep track of all lines/keys you've read using lines[value] = true, and just don't emit lines/keys that satisfy `lines[value] ~= nil`

Comment: @nodecentral, yes, what you wrote should work, but it's better to use a different table. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks all, to create a new separate  ‘unique’ table at the end of it, would I simply add @Mooshua suggestion `lines[value] ~= nil ` and this line  `local unique = {} table.insert(unique, lines[line]) ` both before or after the print command ?

Comment: Correct. If it all works for you, you can accept the answer.